# Entity Framework to existing database without access to master

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have an existing database and connecting to it with EF.  Our SQL user does not have access to the master database.  It only has access to the database that we are using.  How can I instruct EF to stop connecting to master to check if the DB exists.

We are getting the error : The server principal 'AppUser' is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.

The user does exist and the database exists and the user has access to the database.

I've tried

```
Database.SetInitializer<AppDataContext>(null);
```

and that didn't work.

EDIT: Put code in code block so generic brackets show up.

Comment: not sure your syntax is correct. Try specifying the Context like this
Database.SetInitializer<{contextClassName}>(null) in the contructor

Comment: Sorry the copy/paste didn't work.  I'm doing that in both the constructor of the DataContext and in the Startup class

Comment: Are you providing name of database in your connection string?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the Datacontext was extending 'IdentityDbContext'  (We've fixed it now) and that was preventing the SetInitializer from working.

Problem found between keyboard and chair.